# OutOfMemoryException on drawing bezier curves in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

While I am drawing bezier curve with following data, it shows OutOfMemoryException

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
PointF pf0, pf1, pf2, pf3;
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
pen.Width = 2;
pf0 = new PointF(153.649292F, 141.85F);
pf1 = new PointF(153.650925F, 141.848969F);
pf2 = new PointF(153.652557F, 141.848465F);
pf3 = new PointF(153.65419F, 141.848465F);
g.DrawBezier(pen, pf0, pf1, pf2, pf3);
```

If pen.Width is changed as 1.5F, then curve is drawn without showing any exception. Is any possible way to avoid this exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OutOfMemoryException on drawing wide lines with WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975378/outofmemoryexception-on-drawing-wide-lines-with-winforms)

Comment: Are you disposing of disposable resources? Your code doesn't show that you are.

Comment: Looks like your points are too close. One way to avoid it would be to scaletransform the Graphics object, but of course this is hardly a useful idea.. The more natural way is to avoid such close fits; after all floats have only 7 digits, so some of your control points sit on the points... - Still an intersting find!

Comment: On closer inspection this may indeed have the same reason as the link from @Bacon..